# Inspec test cases for windows authentication

Tags: testing, devops, inspec

I am trying to validate (mssql) Sql authentication mode "Integrated" using inspec. I  was not able find any reference. How to pass sql query using ruby as i am having sql query which displays the current sql authentication mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the authentication mode with powershell, see [this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/allen_white/archive/2011/05/19/change-sql-servers-authentication-mode-with-powershell.aspx) for a reference on the `powershell` code and [this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/allen_white/archive/2008/01/09/create-agent-jobs-to-run-powershell-scripts.aspx) on how the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo` assembly is loaded:

> ```
> # Connect to the instance using SMO $s = new-object 
> ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') 'MyServer\MyInstance'
> [string]$nm = $s.Name [string]$mode = $s.Settings.LoginMode
>
> write-output "Instance Name: $nm"
> write-output "Login Mode: $mode"
> ```

Therefore you can write a [`powershell`](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/resources/powershell/) test to achieve what you want:

```
control 'sql auth type' do
  impact 1.0
  ps_script = <<-EOH
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
  $s = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $env:COMPUTERNAME
  [string]$nm = $s.Name
  [string]$mode = $s.Settings.LoginMode

  write-output $mode
  EOH

  describe powershell(ps_script) do
    its('stdout') { should match (/Integrated/)}
  end
end
```